# PHP DOM parse for multiple pages using while loop loads only single page statement multiple times

Tags: php, mysql, web-crawler

I m trying to parse a post related statement from a forum site using PHP dom parser. It works when we insert individual url's of the page, but when we try to apply a while loop logic it kinda prints only one page multiple times..

my code as goes::

```
<?php
    set_time_limit(3600);
      $i = 1;
      $e = 839304-$i;
     while(true){
    require_once('dom/simple_html_dom.php'); 
$html =file_get_html('http://www.usmleforum.com/files/forum/2017/1/'.$e.'.php');
    foreach ($html->find("tr") as $row) {
    $element = $row->find('td.Text2',0);
    if ($element == null) { continue; }
    $textNode = array_filter($element->nodes, function ($n) {
    return $n->nodetype == 3;        //Text node type, like in jQuery     
});
    if (!empty($textNode)) {
    $text = current($textNode);
    echo $text."<br>"; 
}
}
    $i++;
}
?>
```

as the result indicates, it only prints the statement from page 839303, but it prints it multiple times and still loads on.. so its clear that this code is skipping the $i++ line somehow and runs again...

Any help is appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert `$e` inside while loop will fix the problem. but it is an infine loop. so try to give an exit condition for while loop like: `while($i < 100)` or something else.

```
 <?php
    set_time_limit(3600);
      $i = 0;

     while($i < 10){
     $e = 839303 + $i;
    require_once('dom/simple_html_dom.php'); 
$html =file_get_html('http://www.usmleforum.com/files/forum/2017/1/'.$e.'.php');
    foreach ($html->find("tr") as $row) {
    $element = $row->find('td.Text2',0);
    if ($element == null) { continue; }
    $textNode = array_filter($element->nodes, function ($n) {
    return $n->nodetype == 3;        //Text node type, like in jQuery     
});
    if (!empty($textNode)) {
    $text = current($textNode);
    echo $text."<br>"; 
}
}
    $i++;
}
?>
```

Comment: that actually seems to be the solution.. but when i run it changing that, it loads forever without echo ing anything.. can you check on my code, what possibly the mistake, anything else..

Comment: I have change in the code  in `while loop` and in $e value statement  $e = 839303 + $i;

Comment: it works this time but it prints each statement 3 times instead of once .and hence i see only three individual statements printed thrice each.. Do you think i have any for each loop misleaded anywhere..